# Registering last mouse position for smooth drawing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, opengl, mouseevent

I use OpenGL for drawing with mouse in view. Everythings looks OK, but when i draw mouse fast it does not draws in every pixel, there shows up some spacing. I add [image link here](http://s13.postimage.org/t3re0nmdj/Screen_Shot_2012_06_26_at_9_38_08_AM.png). My current mouseDragged code is very simple:

```
- (void) mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)event
{
    location = [self convertPoint: [event locationInWindow] fromView:self];
    NSLog(@"current location (%g,%g)\n",location.y,location.x);
    [self drawSomething];
}
```

Any solution for more correctly registering mouse location? Or maby some way to register currentMouseLocation and previousMouseLocation? Something like iOS function *previousLocationInView:*, so that i could tell OpenGL to draw line between every two points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
- (void) mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)event
{
    location = [self convertPoint: [event locationInWindow] fromView:self];

    NSLog(@"current location (%g,%g)\n",location.y,location.x);
    NSLog(@"previous location (%g,%g)\n",prev_location.y,prev_location.x);

    [self drawSomething];

    prev_location = location;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your 'mouseDragged' you can store the previous location of the mouse or even track the whole path storing the points in the dynamic array. This is why there is no "previous location" property - you can do one for yourself.

There is such a thing as mouse sensitivity, so some skips are inevitable - all you can do is to interpolate, which essentially means your have to draw the line from (prevX, prevY) to (thisX, thisY). If you have all the points stored, then just draw the polyline.

Comment: Will it be enough fast, so user have no lag even on older computer?

Comment: Rendering a few hundreds of lines won't affect the performance much if you're drawing them from a Vertex Buffer Object. If all you need is an image, then keep the offscreen buffer (framebuffer object) with rendered lines and blit this buffer each frame.